# ngOptions where selection causes content to change

Tags: angularjs

I am having a hard time with ngOptions in that I need to have a label have multiple values, where selecting a value will determine what is evaluated in the view. For example, if the label is `Boy`, the value could be `he` or `him`. And then depending on the sentence will depend on whether `he` or `him` is used.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myTest">
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="TestController">
    <select ng-model="test" ng-options="gen.pick group by gen.gender for gen in gender">
    </select>
    <p>{{ gender.value }} is a girl</p>
    <p>{{ gender.value }} is a boy</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Code:**

```
angular.module('myTest', []).controller('TestController', function($scope) {
    $scope.gender = [
      { pick: 'she', gender: 'female'},
      { pick: 'her', gender: 'female'},
      { pick: 'he', gender: 'male'},
      { pick: 'him', gender: 'male'}
    ];
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `ng-show` or `ng-if`:

```
  <span ng-show="test.gender == 'female'">
    <p ng-show="test.pick == 'she'">{{ test.pick }} is a girl</p>
    <p ng-show="test.pick == 'her'">{{ test.pick }} hair is pretty</p>
  </span>
  <p ng-show="test.gender == 'male' && test.pick == 'he'">{{ test.pick }} is a boy</p>
```

A mapping object could clean it up a little:

```
$scope.type = {'she': 'girl', 'he': 'boy' };
...
<p ng-if="type[test.pick]">{{test.pick}} is a {{type[test.pick]}}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me to understand the problem in more detail and solved it as well.

Answer (score 0):

This example is not dissimilar to j.wittwer's approach, but I used a single object containing all of the relevant data and then used Underscore to find and filter data from that source.

It sounds like you're having a tough time conceptualizing a solution, so I thought it might be helpful for you to see a few approaches at what we think you're trying to get at.

**JS** (from controller)

```
$scope.sentenceComponents = [
  { pronoun: 'she', gender: 'girl', sentenceType: 1},
  { pronoun: 'her', gender: 'girl', sentenceType: 2},
  { pronoun: 'he', gender: 'boy', sentenceType: 1},
  { pronoun: 'him', gender: 'boy', sentenceType: 2}
];

$scope.genders = _.uniq(_.pluck($scope.sentenceComponents, 'gender'));
$scope.sentenceTypes = _.uniq(_.pluck($scope.sentenceComponents, 'sentenceType'));

$scope.selectChange = function() {
  $scope.selectedComponents = _.findWhere($scope.sentenceComponents, {gender: $scope.selectedGender, sentenceType: $scope.selectedType});
};

$scope.selectedGender = 'girl';
$scope.selectedType = 1;
$scope.selectChange();
```

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="selectedGender" ng-options="gender for gender in genders" ng-change="selectChange()"></select>
<select ng-model="selectedType" ng-options="sentenceType for sentenceType in sentenceTypes" ng-change="selectChange()"></select>

<p ng-show="selectedComponents.sentenceType == 1">
  {{ selectedComponents.pronoun }} is a {{ selectedComponents.gender }}
</p>
<p ng-show="selectedComponents.sentenceType == 2">
  The {{ selectedComponents.gender }} took the books from {{selectedComponents.pronoun}}
</p>
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/eWMAzRnNv0Y1AiX4Z6fC?p=preview)

Comment: BTW, I'm not assuming that you would have two select boxes - the sentence type select in my code just acts as a way to toggle the types for demo purposes.